# How to make paperclip s3_host_alias available for each environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I currently have something like this on my `has_attached_file` declaration,

```
# Photo.rb
...
:s3_host_alias => 'cdn.mydomain.com'
```

Since the `s3_host_alias` points to a specific bucket that varies on every environment, I'm wondering how could I set `:s3_host_alias` to read a value deppending on its environment.

I was thinking probably a organized way to this would be saving in the same `aws.yml` config file like this,

```
development:
  bucket: development.mydomain.com
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['S3_KEY'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['S3_SECRET'] %>
  s3_host_alias: cdn-dev.mydomain.com

production:
  bucket: media.mydomain.com
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['S3_KEY'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['S3_SECRET'] %>
  s3_host_alias: cdn.mydomain.com

test:
  bucket: test.mydomain.com
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['S3_KEY'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['S3_SECRET'] %>
  s3_host_alias: cdn-test.mydomain.com
```

The problem is that I do not how to call this `s3_host_alias` attribute from the `Photo.rb` model.

Any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by sending a lambda to `s3_host_alias`:

```
s3_host_alias: lambda {|p| p.s3_credentials[:s3_host_alias]}
```

Be sure to also set the `url:` option:

```
url: ':s3_alias_url'
```